# If I have a function that prints as many times as it loops, how can I set up a check that will only print once if all results = 0?

Tags: php, function

If I have a function that prints as many times as it loops, how can I set up a check that will only print once if all sport results combined = 0?

I have an `if` statement within a function called `calc` that states `if` the total `$allTotalPicks !== "0` then echo `<table></table>`. My `else if` statement is the problem and it checks to see if `$allTotalPicks == 0` then `echo` a statement saying `"there is no data..."`. The problem is it is printing the statement as many times as it is looping the function when it is called. There are 7 sports the function checks and currently the `else if` statement `"there is no data..."` prints for every sport that `$allTotalPicks == 0`.

How can I get it to just print once and *ONLY* if `$allTotalPicks == 0` for *ALL* the sports `$sports $i` combined? If only one or two sports has `$allTotalPicks == 0` then the `echo`statement saying `"there is no data..."` should *NOT* print. All sports would need to equal zero to print the `else if` `echo` `"there is no data..."`. Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

You can view the current final results table in action here: https://wsplays.com/results/ on the right sidebar. It is the "per sport" table this code is for. Thanks!

```
<?php
include_once("../../../wp-load.php");
global $wpdb;

$action = $_POST['action'];
$val = $_POST['val'];

if ($action=="persport") {

    if ($val=="playoftheday30") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND playoftheday = 'YES'";
    }

    if ($val=="playoftheday90") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND playoftheday = 'YES'";
    }

    if ($val=="playoftheday365") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND playoftheday = 'YES'";
    }    

    if ($val=="latebreakingplay30") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND latebreakingplay = 'YES'";
    }

    if ($val=="latebreakingplay90") { 
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND latebreakingplay = 'YES'";  
    }

    if ($val=="latebreakingplay365") { 
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND latebreakingplay = 'YES'"; 
    }

    if ($val=="vipyesterday") {
        $interval = " game_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND vipplays = 'YES'";
    }

    if ($val=="vipplays7") {  
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'YES'";  
    }

    if ($val=="vipplays30") {  
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'YES'"; 
    }

    if ($val=="vipplays90") {  
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'YES'";
    }

    if ($val=="vipplays180") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'YES'";  
    }

    if ($val=="vipplays365") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'YES'";
    } 

    if ($val=="yesterday") {
        $interval = " game_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND vipplays = 'NO'";
    }

    if ($val=="past7days") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'NO'";
    }

    if ($val=="thisweek") {
        $interval = "YEAR(game_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND  WEEKOFYEAR(game_date)=WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())";
    }

    if ($val=="thismonth") {
        $interval = " YEAR(game_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(game_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())";
    }

    if ($val=="past30days") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'NO'";
    }

    if ($val=="thisyear") {
        $interval = "  YEAR(game_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
    }

    if ($val=="past365days") {
        $interval = " game_date  BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND vipplays = 'NO'";
    }

    if ($val=="currentseason") {
        $interval = "currentseason";
    }

    function calc($interval,$result_sum,$sum_yourpick,$tot_w,$sport,$sportname) {
        global $wpdb;

        if ($interval=="currentseason") {
            $result = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_sport_seasons WHERE sport=  '".$sport."' AND current_season = 'YES' LIMIT 1";
            $daterange = $wpdb->get_results($result);
            // Display YIP Picks only
            $interval = "game_date BETWEEN '" . $daterange[0]->start_date . "' AND  '" . $daterange[0]->end_date . "' AND vipplays = 'YES'";
        }

        $allRecordWin = 0;
        $allRecordLoss = 0;
        $allRecordPush = 0;
        $allRecordPCT = 0;
        $allRecordUnits = 0;
        $allTotalPicks = 0;
        $allRecordUnitsTemp = 0;

        $result = " SELECT pick_odds,units_play,pick_result FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_picklist WHERE  sport = ".$sport." AND  ".$interval."  ORDER BY game_date DESC";
        $newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);

        foreach($newmeta as $data){
            $pick_odds = 0;
            $units_play = 0;

            if($data->pick_odds!="") $pick_odds = $data->pick_odds;

            if($data->units_play!="") $units_play = $data->units_play;

            if($data->pick_result=='WIN'){
                if ($pick_odds>=100) {
                    $allRecordUnitsTemp = ($pick_odds/100) * $units_play;
                    $allRecordUnitsTemp = Abs(Round($allRecordUnitsTemp, 2));
                    $allRecordUnits = $allRecordUnits + $allRecordUnitsTemp;
                } 

                else if ($pick_odds<100 && $pick_odds!=0) {
                            $allRecordUnitsTemp = (100/$pick_odds) * $units_play;
                            $allRecordUnitsTemp = Abs(Round($allRecordUnitsTemp, 2));
                            $allRecordUnits = $allRecordUnits + $allRecordUnitsTemp;
                }

                else {
                            $allRecordUnitsTemp = (100/$pick_odds) * $units_play;
                            $allRecordUnitsTemp = Abs(Round($allRecordUnitsTemp, 2));
                            $allRecordUnits = $allRecordUnits + $allRecordUnitsTemp;
                }

                $allRecordWin = $allRecordWin + 1;
                $allTotalPicks = $allTotalPicks + 1;

            } // END WIN 

            else if ($data->pick_result=='LOSS') {
                    $allRecordUnits = $allRecordUnits - $units_play;
                    $allRecordUnits = Round($allRecordUnits, 2);
                    $allRecordLoss = $allRecordLoss + 1;
                    $allTotalPicks = $allTotalPicks + 1;
            } 

            else if ($data->pick_result=='PUSH') {
                    $allRecordPush = $allRecordPush + 1;
            }
        } // END foreach

        if ($allTotalPicks>0) {

            $allRecordPCT = ($allRecordWin / $allTotalPicks) * 100;
            $allRecordPCT = Round($allRecordPCT, 0);
        }

        if ($allRecordUnits>0) {
            $all = "+".$allRecordUnits;
        }

        else {
            $all = $allRecordUnits;
        }

        /** *********************************************************/
        /** *********************************************************/

        if ($allTotalPicks !== 0) {    
            echo"
                <table class='sidebar_result b'>
                        <tr class='hdr_2'>
                            <td colspan='5' >$sportname</td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr class='hdr_2'>
                            <td>W</td>
                            <td>L</td>
                            <td>P</td>
                            <td>PCT</td>
                            <td>UNITS</td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr class='hdr_3'>
                            <td>$allRecordWin</td>
                            <td>$allRecordLoss</td>
                            <td>$allRecordPush</td>
                            <td>".$allRecordPCT."%</td>
                            <td>$all</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>";
        }
```

This is where the problem starts:

```
        else if ($allTotalPicks == 0) { 
            echo "<p style='font-size: 14px; color: #F8F8F8; padding: 10px; text-align: left;'>There is no data for the current selection.<br>Please choose another option.</p>";
        }

        /** *********************************************************/
        /** *********************************************************/
    } // END function

    $sportname = "";
    $bidsys_options = get_option('bidsys_options');
        for ( $i=1; $i<8; $i++ ) {
            if ( $bidsys_options-> sportsstatus[$i] != "Disabled" ) {
                $sportname =  $bidsys_options->sportsname[$i];
                $sport = $i;   

         calc($interval,$result_sum,$sum_yourpick,$tot_w,$sport,$sportname);

            } 
        }
} // END else persport
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
        else if ($allTotalPicks == 0) { 

        }

        return $allTotalPicks;

        /** *********************************************************/
        /** *********************************************************/
    } // END function
```

Then, you could have something like...

```
    for ( $i=1; $i<8; $i++ ) {
        if ( $bidsys_options-> sportsstatus[$i] != "Disabled" ) {
            $sportname =  $bidsys_options->sportsname[$i];
            $sport = $i;   

         $total_picks_all_sports += calc($interval,$result_sum,$sum_yourpick,$tot_w,$sport,$sportname);
        } 
    }

    if ( 0 == $total_picks_all_sports ) {
        echo "<p style='font-size: 14px; color: #F8F8F8; padding: 10px; text-align: left;'>There is no data for the current selection.<br>Please choose another option.</p>";
    } else {
        /* Total picks is not zero, do something else. */
    }
```

The variable `$total_picks_all_sports` is the total number of picks for all sports and only if that is zero you write the message to the page.

Comment: This worked and the answer seems obvious now! ;) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `break` keyword described here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

> `break` ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.
>
> `break` accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. The default value is 1, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'stop', 'five');
while (list(, $val) = each($arr)) {
    if ($val == 'stop') {
        break;    /* You could also write 'break 1;' here. */
    }
    echo "$val<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Noah I reviewed the `break` keyword but I don't see how it applies in this scenario unless I'm missing something. I must be asking the wrong question but I'm not sure how else to ask it.